# TestNG--java.lang.AssertionError: expected [5] but found [5]

Tags: testng

My TestNG test implementation throws an error despite the expected value matches with the actual value.

Here is the TestNG code:

```
int rowCount=driver.findElements(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("xpath"))).size();
Assert.assertEquals(rowCount,prop.getProperty("row[]"));
```

I got the the following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [5] but found [5]
```

Answer (score 4):

You are comparing an int to a string. Try converting the type before comparing the values.

```
import org.testng.Assert;

public class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Integer rowCount = 1;
        String stringValue = "1";
//      Assert.assertEquals(rowCount,stringValue); //this fails

        Assert.assertEquals(rowCount,Integer.valueOf(stringValue)); //this passes


    }
}
```